# Proper way to export interface of an array to avoid "Property 'push' does not exist on type..." in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I need to export 2 interfaces, with the first one being:

```
export interface DataEntry {
   title: string,
   content: string
}
```

Now for the second one, I would like to export the class as an array of the interface `DataEntry`. I am aware that we can do this when declare the variable directly:

```
let data: DataEntry[] = [];
```

However, I would like to be able to export that `DataEntry[]` interface to `DataSource`. Below is my attempt:

```
export interface DataSource {
    [index: number]: DataEntry
}
```

This, however, will throw an error when I try to do anything:

```
let data: DataSource = [];
//Error: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'DataSource'
data.push({ title: 'Title', content: 'Content' });
```

Technically, no array operations exists on the variable `data` which is of interface `DataSource`.

**What is the proper way to export the interface DataSource?**

Comment: Is there a reason `DataSource` needs to be a separate interface instead of `DataEntry[]`?

Comment: @VLAZ: I am writing a library and I want to make it easy for my team so that they will know exactly what the @Input() interface will be without having to look into the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use type alias

```js
export type DataSource = DataEntry[];
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and @Aakash Garg's above? Can you enlighten me?

Comment: It is shorter :). And it is not an interface: I don't want anyone to extend / implement the interface as it is a bad practice.

Comment: there is no difference between the top statement and defining your data as let data: DataEntry[] = []. You are just exporting a type. In your question you wanted an interface which you can define extended functionality. If you wanted this there is actually no need of DataSource. You can use DataEntry like let data:DataSource[] = []. Please be specific in your question what you exactly want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You DataSource interface should be like :-

```
interface DataSource extends Array<DataEntry>{}
```

Explaination

Earlier you were declaring interface like

export interface DataSource {
    [index: number]: DataEntry
   }

This means object of DataEntry
   you could declare and use it like

```
   let data: DataSource = {};
   dataSource[0] = {title: 'ABC', content: 'ABC'}
```

The above might seem like you assigned an object at 0 index, in actual you set key as 0 and its value as the object above.

My interface just extended an Array of datasource. Because Array is a class which accepts a generic type T. I passed it T as DataEntry.

Comment: This is perfect! Can you please briefly explain to me why it works that way?

Comment: added explanation above